# Spark 3.2.4 Dataset ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark 3.2.4 and I have the following problem with DataSets.

I have a DataFrame called data that I am casting to a DataSet using a case class.

```
case class logs(event_time: Option[String] = None, 
    event_type: Option[String] = None, 
    product_id: Option[Int] = None,
    category_id: Option[Long] = None,
    category_code: Option[String] = None,
    brand: Option[String] = None,
    price: Option[Double] = None,
    user_id: Option[Int] = None,
    user_session: Option[String] = None 
    )
```

I then cast my DataFrame to a DataSet without any exceptions.

```
import spark.implicits._
val typedData = data.as[logs]
```

If I run a show on typedData I get 20 records just as expected and typedData is of type Dataset[logs].

```
typedData.show()
```

However, when I try to map the data I get a long exception

```
import spark.implicits._
typedData.map(x => x.price.map(_ * 10)).show()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 84) (lukass-mbp.lan executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: class $iw cannot be cast to class $iw ($iw is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader @872f2a4; $iw is in unnamed module of loader scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader @147b2793)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2450)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2399)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2398)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2398)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1156)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1156)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1156)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2638)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2580)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2569)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2224)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2245)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:492)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:445)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2728)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:806)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:765)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:774)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class $iw cannot be cast to class $iw ($iw is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader @872f2a4; $iw is in unnamed module of loader scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader @147b2793)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:350)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
  ... 3 more
```

However, there are no issues if I map tuples as below.

```
val doubleTyped = typedData.select(col("product_id").as[Option[Int]],col("price").as[Option[Double]])

doubleTyped.map(x =>(x._1, x._2.map(_ * 10) )).show()
```